# Proof that $i$ is not a real number

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-writing, solution-verification

This will not be a very rigorous proof of that $i=\sqrt{-1}$ is not a real number.

Using the properties of the $\mathbf{R}$:

1. The real numbers are closed under multiplication
2. The real numbers can negative, zero or positive

Assuming that $i\in \mathbf{R}$,

Therefore working on three cases:

Case 1: $i=0$

If $i=0 \Rightarrow i\cdot i=0 \cdot i\Rightarrow -1=0$ which is clearly wrong.

Hence $i\not=0$

Case 2: $i>0$

If $i>0 \Rightarrow i\cdot i>0 \cdot i\Rightarrow -1>0$ which is once again clearly wrong

Hence $i\not>0$

Case 3: $i<0$

If $i<0 \Rightarrow i\cdot i>0 \cdot i\Rightarrow -1>0$

Hence $i\not<0$

Henceforth $i$ is not positive, neither is it negative nor is it zero.

This can only be possible if $i\notin \mathbf{R}$

I'd like to know if this is a good proof if it was backed up group theory.

Comment: Best proof I have seen that $i$ is not a real number

Answer (score 5):

This is correct, but there is no need to consider $3$ different cases. You could just say that if $i\in\Bbb R$, then $i^2\geqslant0$. But this is false, since $i^2=-1$.

Comment: But if we say $i^2 \geq 0$ aren't we starting off with contradiction that $-1 \geq 0$

Comment: But also if start with $x^2 \geq 0$ isn't that a cycling reasoning as we have the example that $i^2=-1$?

Comment: Of course. This is a proof by contradiction.

Comment: Just like your proof. Your task was to prove that $i\notin\Bbb R$, but you started with “Assuming that $i\in\Bbb R$”.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative approach

By definition, $i^2 = -1.$  A property of the real numbers is that for all $x \in \Bbb{R}, x^2 \geq 0.$

Therefore, $i$ can't be a real number.

Comment: But when we assume that $i$ is real, then we have an example that contradicts that very statement right? Isn't it better to approach this with a more fundamental property such as the closure under multiplication?

Comment: @Boy Agreed with you. This seems circular. Plus it doesn’t answer the explicit question *you* put at the end of your post.

Comment: @gen-ℤreadytoperish Remember, I posted an answer after Jose Carlos Santos did.  Jose Carlos Santos answered the OP's question, and I agree completely with that answer.  That is, I also consider the OP's proof valid.  I chose my proof because it goes right to the definition.

Comment: @Boy See my previousl comment.

Answer (score 2):

I'll address a point of confusion the OP has had with existing answers. Let's begin by proving the given properties of $\Bbb R$, together with rules such as $a,\,b>0\implies ab>0$, imply $x^2\ge0$ for $x\in\Bbb R$: if $x\in\Bbb R$ either $x\ge0$ so $x^2\ge0$, or $x<0$ so $x^2>0$. This is a consequence of our assumptions, not a further assumption beyond our allowed scope. So when we note this contradicts $i^2=-1<0$ if $i\in\Bbb R$, we have proven $i\notin\Bbb R$; we don't need to worry that maybe we've discovered a counterexample to a conjecture.

Comment: Okay, I do get your point but your method does not avoid the problem of circular reasoning. While proving the properties such as $a,b>0\Rightarrow ab>0$ we are still still overlooking the fact that we have counterexample while proving those very properties. So we shall start by saying that $i\in \mathbf{R} $ then attempt to show the properties of the Real Numbers, we can prove closure and commutativity and associativity under addition and multiplication. But when we approach other properties such as the $x^2 \geq 0$ we already have a counterexample to disprove it.

Comment: @Boy It's weird that you accept $e^{x\pi}>0$ for real $x$ but are worried maybe positive reals don't have a positive product. The point is each approach discussed on this page shows certain sets of claims about $\Bbb R$, each including $\exists i\in\Bbb R(i^2=-1)$, are inconsistent. *The point of the exercise is to accept the rest of the set.* If you don't concede e.g. $a,\,b>0\implies ab>0$, you're not talking about $(\Bbb R,\,\times)$ any more; you're changing the set, binary operation or both.

Comment: Oh no please don’t be mistaken I don’t accept the proof for the $e^{i\pi}>0$. I just like its elegance. Its stull wrong as it uses exponentiation which is might end up in some sort of circular reasoning.

Comment: @Boy Well, at the time I wrote my comment you'd only praised that answer. Anyway, there's no circularity here, only an implicit definition of real numbers' arithmetic through the axioms which the exercise asks you to use to prove $\neg\exists i\in\Bbb R(i^2=-1)$. You can't prove it without assuming *something* that characterizes this number system, because e.g. $\exists i\in\Bbb C(i^2=-1)$.

Comment: So you’re saying that the real numbers should be defined by the operation that $x^2 \geq 0$ ?

Comment: @Boy No, that's a *consequence of* the definition, as is $\neg\exists x\in\Bbb R(x^2<0)$.

Comment: @boy Nobody says that $e^{i \pi}>0$. This is the method of $\color{blue}{ \text{proof by contradiction!}}$. We say , $\color\red{{ \text{if} ~ i\in\mathbb R, ~\text{then} ~ e^{i \pi} >0}}$ by definion of $a^x$ with real exponent. If we think so, your proof must also be wrong.  Where is your proof? if $a>0$, then $ac>0, \forall c\in\mathbb R^+$..if $ac<0, ...$ Then you have to define the inequality! What is the definition of $$\color {red}{>,<}$$? is not it? Thus, your proof is invalid.

Comment: @lone student well yes you’re right. But that’s where group theory comes in.

Comment: @Boy We don't *say* $x^2\ge0$ for reals, we *prove* $x^2\ge0$ for reals. In particular, $x^2+1=0$ is no more satisfiable in $\Bbb R$ than $e^x=0$ is satisfiable in $\Bbb R$ (or for that matter $\Bbb C$). The "response" to a proof by contradiction that an equation isn't satisfiable shouldn't be, "but I wrote down notation that makes it look like the equation is satisfied, so how do you know it can't be?" *The proof you're "responding" to is how we know.*

Comment: @J.G. I get your point but my problem with your proof is that we say $x^2 \geq 0$ for all reals. Then we say that i doesn’t follow this property hence its not real. Take the equation $x^2+1=0$ for example. Now here $x$ is $i$ of course. But now we try to find i in the reals. My proof is how we search for it. And in the end we find that its not a part of the real numbers. In your proof, we say that real numbers have so and so properties and i doesn’t fit in. I won’t accept your $x^2 \geq 0$ part because it seems to prove this property that already has a counterexample

Comment: @Boy You're not allowed not to accept $\forall x\in\Bbb R(x^2\ge0)$, because I proved it. What are you doing, making $i\in\Bbb R$ an axiom? If so, all you're doing is adopting inconsistent axioms, which don't stop a proof that $\forall x\in\Bbb R(x^2\ge0)$ going through; that's been proven by multiple answers here, mine included. You've not given a counterexample, because $i\notin\Bbb R$. Instead $i\in\Bbb C$. Nobody can prove $\forall x\in\Bbb C(x^2\ge0)$.

Comment: @J.G. I wanted to ask this thing.  I'm almost not interested in axiom systems.  Because definitions are essentially university level.  Here is what I want to ask.  Aren't real numbers a special case of complex numbers?  Assuming $ b = 0 $ from the formula $ z=a + bi $.  What should we understand from this definition?  $z\in\mathbb C$ ? For example, is it inconsistent to write like this? It is impossible to prove that  $$\forall x\in\Bbb C \setminus \mathbb R(x^2\ge0)$$ Thanks.

Comment: @lonestudent Well, you can't prove that because it's false, because it has counterexample $x=i$. Some truths of $\Bbb R$ extend to $\Bbb C$ while others don't. But when they don't, their counterexamples will always have nonzero imaginary part, so will be non-real.

Comment: @J.G Thanks for explanations. Yes! I missed an important word/symbol **for all** $\forall$. So, I think these are the  equivalent representation: Impossibility of $$\forall x\in\Bbb C(x^2\ge0)$$ or 
  $$ x\in\Bbb C \setminus \mathbb R(x^2\ge0) $$ Am I thinking right now?

Comment: @lonestudent If $\forall x\in A(\phi(x))$, then $\forall x\in B(\phi(x))$ iff $\forall x\in B\setminus A(\phi(x))$.

Comment: @J.G. I read a bit about the axiomatic definition of the real numbers and from that it is clear to me that your proof is indeed correct. I do apologise if I was a bit rude and thank you for spending so much time explaining this to me. My goal was to approach this proof as carefully and skeptically as possible to avoid making errors. I hope you think my proof is careful enough though

Comment: @J.G. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, this answer is based on the fact that $ i ^ 2 = -1$ anyway.  But for me it's a different beauty of mathematics.

If, $i\in\mathbb R$, then $e^{i \pi}>0$. But, this contradicts with [Euler's well-known identity](http://Euler%27s%20identity).

$$e^{i \pi}=-1$$

Comment: Your proof is quite elegant and simple.

Comment: @Boy you're welcome.

Comment: But your proof can’t go with group theory so I can’t accept it so let me make that clear. I’m just saying that I like it

Comment: @Boy My answer has absolutely nothing to do with Group theory.  Why should $e ^ x> 0,~ \forall x\in\mathbb R$  I can give you the proof of that. If you want proof of Euler's formula, I can give. But I cannot add that to the answer. Because it doesn't match your question..My goal here is not to define the axiom set.  Because the formula I use is already the result of certain definitions.

Comment: Yes, but I’m looking for a proof which can be backed by group theory. Also I just wanted to know if my proof was right, which I understood is correct.

Comment: @Boy Whether you use any theory or not, this cannot invalidate my proof.